# Use mysqldump backup and restore Mysql database on Windows batch file

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

There are a little different to do this on Windows.

- Create a bat file, contains mysql database backup command text.
- Create a task in Windows Task Schedule to execute this bat file.

Then you could config this task as your wish, and do restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Backup Database.

```
@ECHO OFF
set filename=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot -p123456 -hlocalhost databaseName > C:\Danny\MySql-BackUp\databaseName-%filename%.sql
```

Format Explain:
mysqldump.exe –e –u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [database name] > C:[filename].sql

Run batch file, you will get a sql file contains all database info.

2:Restore database using backup sql.

Get into Mysql root path in CMD, and execute below command:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql.exe -uroot -p123456 -hlocalhost databaseName < C:\Danny\MySql-BackUp\databaseName-201801311848321.sql
```

Comment: If your bat file execute failed, maybe caused by wrong data format. You could add "echo %data%" to show your data format and add "parse" at the end of bat file to avoid command window close automatically. And then to format your own filename.

Comment: You could also set character-set for your backup sql file. Just modify bat command like this: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot -p123456 --default-character-set=utf8 -hlocalhost databaseName > C:\Danny\MySql-BackUp\databaseName-%filename%.sql